# "NO tuple" message while running spork on Windows7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork

I am trying to get the spork + rspec combination to work with my rails 3 installation. I am using Ruby 1.9.3p194.

I run the spork server and it starts with following message:

```
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
   -- build slave 1...   -- build slave 2...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
```

In a separate window, I run rspec:

```
rspec spec --drb
```

Now the spork window displays the following message:

```
Running tests with args ["--color", "spec"]...
- NO tuple
Done.

  --> DRb magazine_slave_service: 1 provided...
  --> DRb magazine_slave_service: 2 provided...
```

And the tests are not executed. Has anybody successfully managed to get rspec + spork to work on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, you waited long enough until Spork is ready? While Ruby on Rails in general is slow on Windows, Spork also!

You have to wait until...

```
--> DRb magazine_slave_service: 1 provided... 
--> DRb magazine_slave_service: 2 provided...
```

...and then start your rspec...

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec --drb
```

...spork gives out this message:

```
Running tests with args ["--color", "spec"]...
<-- take tuple(1); slave.run...
```